# Android View below another in FrameLayout not work

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have such code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="center map"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

        <pl.jawegiel.endlessblow.other.GameSurface
            android:id="@+id/gameSurface"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        (...)

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/left_rv"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#22FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#080"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/right_rv"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="#99FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#080"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The problem is that my Button is not below GameSurface.

I put this Button as first one counting on that it will be below GameSurface but it does not work.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Why you don't use LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout? Just use it with vertical orientation and add childs from top to bottom as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change FrameLayout to another kind of ViewGroup. FrameLayout is a a type of ViewGroup where one View is on top of another one. Like Layers in a cake.

Putting one below another is not possible in FrameLayout

The easiest solution might be to change FrameLayout with LinearLayout and of course, remember to add android:orientation attribute to it.

NOTE: I suggest you to learn ConstraintLayout, which can replace nearly every type of nested ViewGroups including FrameLayout and RelativeLayout :-)

Comment: If I change to LinearLayout then android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" does not work and still the button is not below GameSurface what I want to achieve. But looking for example at this example: https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-framelayout-with-examples we see that the FrameLayout is what I should to apply in this case as those textviews in example are successfully put on top of ImageView.

Comment: @Kiubaz TextView's are ON TOP of the ImageView but not below. You want to place your button below the ImageView. Use LinearLayout and set orientation: vertical. Then use android:gravity="center_vertical" to set it to the desired position. In that case, you need to place the Button below GameSurface inside XML and also LinearLayout needs to have layout_height = "match_parent"

Comment: @Kiubaz change to linearLayout, set orientation, change order - button as the last child.

Answer (score 1):

This you can't achieve with `FrameLayout`, this is because FrameLayout is usually used to show only one child. Even tho it can show more child views they are just placed on top of each other. This is explained in the answer above. Each ViewGroup has its own pros and cons and the best Layout for this is LinearLayout. LinearLayout can place your child's one below another or one next to another, based on `android:orientation` attribute you can use. Values are `vertical` and `horizontal`. You understand from that which one should be used here.

Therefore, what you need to do is simply change your `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout`. So this is how it looks in my XML:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

After that, you just place your child views in order you want to show them. So, in my case I have an `ImageView` and a `Button`, placed in that order, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gameSurface"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_user"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="center map"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I get this:

[image]